# I can't edit any question/answer on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, edits

Today I edited two questions. But after someone approved my edit, I can no longer edit any posts of Stack Overflow.

What is the problem? Why is the edit option disabled for me?

Comment: Looks like some bad reviews - what I can see is good edits and bad reviewers.

Comment: @Bart sorry this duplicate.but what is the problem

Comment: A significant portion of your suggested edits has been rejected. As explained in the duplicate this means you will be edit-banned. This lasts 7 days.

Comment: Hover over the disabled "edit" link and you'll see the reason as a tooltip.

Comment: I can see your [5 suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1197031/zala-janaksinh?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) were `rejected` so you are automatically suspended to suggest more edit till next 7 days.

Comment: @Bart then any option that why to banned me?to see the reason?

Comment: Your edits are mostly bad. [The comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2190328) pretty much sums it up in three words: "this is worse". You replace bad grammar with equally bad grammar or even worse, many times.

Comment: ok thank now my question is duplicate then i remove from here?my self?

Comment: Yes you should be able to delete it.

Comment: If I look at your edits, and even at what I had to correct in this question, perhaps you should not be editing for language for a while. Improve your English and then try again. That may sound blunt, but it's the biggest problem I see.

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh one other suggestion when you start editing again... don't just write "Improve Question Quality" or "Improve Answer Quality" as the edit comment.  You edits should always improve the quality of the post, so that comment is pretty much worthless.  Be a bit more specific but still keep it short, such as "Improve Code formatting, capitalization, grammar" or something more descriptive to explain what you are doing (and maybe why).  The more complete your comment is, the easier it will be on the reviewers to understand what you did, and could help your approval rate.

Comment: Given that this is in the Android tag (as [Hans Passant once put it, *"Android is the toilet-bowl of Stack Overflow, only out-voted by the cesspool of the Facebook tag."*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/week-2-of-the-summer-of-love-researching-comments/)*), it may be useful to look in other tags to familiarise yourself with higher-quality English, say the [Scala tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala).